# is there a way to index date time column without specifying the datetime column name while reading csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a .csv file that has 2 date-time columns, the normal way to index them is

`pd.read_csv("data.csv",index_col=['date1','date2'])`,

is there a way to automatically index the date-time column without specifying the column name, because i am making a template code that should run for other data files also, where i cant specify index column names manually.

Comment: Do you need set index by positions like `pd.read_csv("data.csv",index_col=[0,1])` ?

Comment: for an example if a new data file is selected from an API to be used in my python code, there i cant give index positions or column names for every new data ,since i will not have an option to change the code everytime. so what can i do at this point @jezrael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the index is of datetime once its read in and if its not loop through and set the index to one that is datetime

Example:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",index_col=['date1','date2'])

if (!isinstance(df.index, pd.DatetimeIndex)):
    for column in df:
        if(isinstance(column, pd.DatetimeIndex)):
            df.set_index(column, inplace=True)
            break
```

Comment: can you give some example so that i can understand better